# Rails before_filter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

help me fix the problem:

i have two devise model (User and Admin)

and i have some post model and controller with routes:

```
/posts
/posts/80
/posts/80/edit
```

and i want that:
admin has all access 
user has access to:

```
/post
   and 
/post/80 ( if he is creator of this post )
```

I done this:

```
    class PostsController < ApplicationController
        before_filter :check_guest_logged_in!, :except => [:index, :show]

.
.
.
    private

    def check_guest_logged_in! 
      if user_signed_in?
        authenticate_user!  

      elsif admin_signed_in?
        authenticate_admin!
      else
        redirect_to root_path
      end   
    end
```

but in this case if user is authorize he can put in browser

```
/posts/80/edit
```

and he get access ( even if he is not the creator of this post )

**how can i fix this ?**

i want something like that
        private

```
    def check_guest_logged_in! 
      if user_signed_in?
        authenticate_user!

    if ( current_user.id == @post.user.id ) 
    else
      return false;
    end     

      elsif admin_signed_in?
        authenticate_admin!
      else
        redirect_to root_path
      end   
    end
```

but its not work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My suggestion would be to use the CanCan gem

https://github.com/ryanb/cancan

Here's an excellent railscast on it

http://railscasts.com/episodes/192-authorization-with-cancan

With cancan you can do something like this

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
    user ||= User.new # guest user (not logged in)
    if user.admin?
      can :manage, :all
    else
      can :read, :all
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: The fundamental problem with your code is that you're only checking if the user is logged in, and not if they are the owner of that post. You'll need an account_id column in your posts table and you can simply do a before filter and check if the current_user is the same as the posts owner, but cancan is really a better option since it's easily configurable and keeps your code DRY